# Spring boot using Drools ui designer

Tags: spring-boot, drools

I want to implement a central **spring boot** application that responsible for designing **business rules** with [Drools](https://www.drools.org/). [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/drools-spring-integration) is an example for integrating spring boot with drools. I need to use a **UI designer** for generating rules **in database**(rather than drl file), But I don't know how it's possible. I've searched a lot and seen somethings like drools workbench , KIE server, Guvnor and ..., but I don't know what are they and which one is suitable for me. Is there any resources or good documentation for **using drools UI in Spring boot application?**

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to implement a rules engine, I've searched and choose between Camunda DMN and Drools. I would like to recommend you to use **Camunda DMN**. It's much more easier to use for rules than Drools.
Camunda DMN has a Spring Boot - starter too. 
Camunda has an App (*Camunda Modeler*) where you can define rules with a simple to use GUI and then deploy them to your Camunda Server. They will be stored in a database. If you want you can integrate your application with another database, so that you can download rules from your Camunda Server and then store them in your Application Database.

> A very good and simple example of using Camunda DMN with Spring Boot:
>   [spring-boot-camunda-dmn-example](https://github.com/bobbyz-dk/spring-boot-camunda-dmn-example)

So looks a simple DMN-rule. It will be stored in **XML**-Format and you can store it as a String in your Database.
[image: camunda dmn rule]